# Fastlane - push certs to repo

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

I've submitted an app to App Store successfully using Fastlane. However I didn't had write permissions for the certs repo and I was not able to push them. Is there any way(action/command) to push the certs I have locally to the repo?

Answer (score 1):

If you just re-run match again with same parameters, it should simply detect that certificates are already created, and push them to GIT.

You can also use `--force` option to recreate the certicates again.

Comment: Would existing apple push and voip push certificates be overwritten?